# Importar archivos de audio a la carpeta Resources

Tags: c#

estoy que busco y busco y nada, necesito importar archivos de sonidos a mi proyecto específicamente a la Carpeta Resources del proyecto, he probado arrastrando el archivo hacia la carpeta Resources, tambien probé copiando el archivos en la ruta del proyecto desde el explorador de windows, en ambos casos se añade, pero al querer usarlo en el codigo no lo reconoce. Los archivos de sonido necesito que se alojen en el proyecto y no cargarlo desde una ruta en especifico. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que muestres la manera como intentas obtener los archivos, por que hay varias formas de leerlo: como archivos de una ruta, como recurso embebido en la dll, etc. De acuerdo como vayas a leer tienes que cambiar las propiedades del archivo en tu proyecto

Comment: hola gracias por responder, estoy haciendo de esta forma:   this.pctEstadoConexion.Image = CapaPresentacion.Properties.Resources.warning; Hasta el momento estoy llamando asi a las imagenes que tengo en el carpeta Resources